# find . character in regular expression problems

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having trouble replacing things like "`joe.`" in a regular expression. Here's the code

```
var objects = new Array("joe","sam");  
code = "joe.id was here so was sam.id";  
for(i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {  
    re = new RegExp(objects[i]+"\.", "g");  
    code = code.replace(re, "stan ");  
}
```

I've tried `\.`, `\\.`, `\\\.`, but none of those seem to work.

Comment: I just tried your code in the Google Chrome Javascript console. It worked for me.

Comment: Works for me - http://jsfiddle.net/AyEue/

Comment: @jlafay: I believe the legitimate use of the tag is for the DOT language used by GraphViz, and the associated utility.

Comment: @jlafay: Yes, "dot" has a tag, but it doesn't refer to the `.` character.  (I was just about to add a tag wiki consisting of just a `.` character, but there was already one there -- which I've just edited to add some more information.)

Comment: @Jefromi That makes more sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code works perfectly with `"\\."`

```
var objects = new Array("joe","sam");  
code = "joe.id was here so was sam.id";  
for(i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {  
    re = new RegExp(objects[i]+"\\.", "g");  
    code = code.replace(re, "stan ");  
}
```

`"\\."` creates the string `\.`, which fits the bill.

Comment: I must have missed something. Or I'm seeing another problem. Thanks for verifying this for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could use`[.]` instead of escaping.